# How do I (re) subscribe to email notifications from my global inbox?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox, email-notification

I got an email notification in an old email account about (new) items in my Stack Overflow global inbox. I wanted to change that to a more current email address, but I accidentally clicked on the unsubscribe link in the email and was instantly unsubscribed.

Now I can't for the life of me find where to re-subscribe to global inbox notifications...

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/ ?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the [preferences tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) in our [user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current):

> [image]

Leading to:

> [image]